# Java File io. How to get char without using streamclass or any way to read char from the next line in txt

Tags: java

I have been wondering like is there any way we can read char from a txt file without using stream class in java. i know stream class is much more efficient. But i want to read file line by line.

For example:

Name(String read this)

sex(char read in next line)

So can I use stream class for this purpose or is there any way to read char using simple scanner?

Comment: You mean like [Scanner.nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) or [BufferedReader.readLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())?

Comment: i meant the Scanner.nextLine(); i dont know about Buffer that much

Comment: Where are you having trouble?  If you only care about the first character in a line, just examine that character in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in a try-with-resources block for proper closing

```
try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/your/file/location"))) {
    //read the first line
    String line = reader.readLine();
    //keep reading until done
    while (line != null) {
        //process line
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```